# I want to change my email address

Tags: support, login

I recently stopped using the email address that I log-in with. I want to change it to the current one that I use. Example: Change it from me@gmail.com then type in the password to me2@gmail.com and update my password. Sorry if this is a duplicate question!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add and remove email address log-ins [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/25973) (user specific).

More generally, click on: your user profile > edit profile settings > my logins

Comment: When I click on the "remove" it ask me if I am sure I want  to do that. Being that is my only log in credential, your saying that it will allow me to re-enter the email address I want?

Comment: there appears to be the option to *add* your new email address as an alternative log-in - why don't you try that first